# Xamarin.Forms MVVM How to load bindable Picker with data from async process in ViewModel?

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, picker

In my ViewModel i want o load the Picker source RegionName data from an Azure Region table. I extract data from table in an async method but the Picker displays an empty List even after ObservableCollection or List has changed or crashes.

When using PropertyChanged on the ListRegion list itself the app crashes.

In my models:

```
 public class Region
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string RegionName { get; set; }
    }
```

In my RegisterPage.xaml:

```
<Picker SelectedIndex="{Binding RegionsSelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Regions}"
                Margin="0,15,0,0"
                Title="Select a region">
</Picker>
```

in my RegisterPage.cs:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class RegisterPage : ContentPage
{
    RegisterViewModel registerVM;

    public RegisterPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        registerVM = new RegisterViewModel();
        this.BindingContext = registerVM;   
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
    }
```

in my RegisterPageViewModel:

```
public class RegisterViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        ApiServices _apiServices = new ApiServices();


        public RegisterViewModel()
        {      
           initializePickerAsync();
        }


        async private void initializePickerAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var regionsList = await App.MobileService.GetTable<Models.Region>().ToListAsync();

                List<string> regionsStringList = new List<string>();

                foreach (Models.Region reg in regionsList)
                {
                    regionsStringList.Add(reg.RegionName);
                }

                Regions = regionsStringList;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        /*


    private RegisterViewModel (ObservableCollection<Models.Region> regionData)
        {

            ObservableCollection<string> regionDataAsStringList = new ObservableCollection<string>();

            foreach (Models.Region r in regionData)
            {
                regionDataAsStringList.Add(r.RegionName);
            }

            this.Regions = regionDataAsStringList;
        }

        async public static Task<RegisterViewModel> BuildViewModelAsync()
        {
            ObservableCollection<Models.Region> tmpRegionData = new ObservableCollection<Models.Region>(await App.MobileService.GetTable<Models.Region>().ToListAsync());

            return new RegisterViewModel(tmpRegionData);
        }
        */

        int regionsSelectedIndex = 0;

        public int RegionsSelectedIndex
        {
            get
            {
                return regionsSelectedIndex;
            }
            set
            {
                if (regionsSelectedIndex != value)
                {
                    regionsSelectedIndex = value;

                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(RegionsSelectedIndex));

                    if (regionsSelectedIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        Region = Regions[regionsSelectedIndex];
                    }               
                }
            }
        }

       // public ObservableCollection<Region> Regions {get;set}

        public List<string> Regions
        {
            get
            {
                return Regions;
            }
            set
            {
                if (Regions != value)
                {
                    Regions = value;

                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Regions));

                }
            }
        }



        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you seem to be doing a lot of unnecessary creating and assigning of different lists of data.  You should be able to create your ObservableCollection ONCE and then add your data to it, something like this

in your ViewModel

```
ObservableCollection<Region> Regions { get; set; }

public RegisterViewModel()
{      
    Regions = new ObservableCollection<Region>();
}

public async void GetData()
{
    var regionsList = await App.MobileService.GetTable<Models.Region>().ToListAsync();

    foreach (Models.Region reg in regionsList)
    {
        Regions.Add(reg);
    }
}
```

in your page

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    await registerVM.GetData();
}
```

Comment: since regionsList is a List<Regions> and the picker is going to only get data from this async task, you can just do `Regions= new ObservableCollection<Region>(regionsList );` to add the data in the observable collection, can't you?

Comment: One question I still have though, I noticed the RegisterViewModel() constructor fires twice, any idea why?

Comment: I don't see any reason for it to do so